# Java spring BasicDataSource displaying query result

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a `BasicDataSource` object with its jdbc configuration set. If i execute a query, e.g. : `'select sysdate from dual'` , i would get back the resultset :e.g. `'30/01/2016 20:20:15'`. However, if i was to run this query as a script in SQL Developer / Toad, I would get

```
"
SYSDATE  
---------
31-JAN-16
1 row selected.
"
```

I am interested in obtaining the same output log as if i would be executing the query in oracle as a script. How could this be achieved?. Is there a library/function that i could use to return the result in the format i require?

Answer (score 0):

This is only presentation matter, so it should be handle in application layer.

With SQL only you could use [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) to format date as string with specific form:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY') AS result
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of a `DATE` value in a string form is defined by the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F.htm#REFRN10119)  parameter.

It is modifiable in a session (with ALTER SESSION) as demonstrated below

```
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

PARAMETER                      VALUE       
------------------------------ ------------------ 
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SS

select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE         
-----------------
31.01.16 19:07:09

alter session set  nls_date_format="dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss";

select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE           
-------------------
31/01/2016 19:07:29
```

Note also that in JDBC you typically use [getDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28int%29) which fetch a `Date` object, so no conversion to string is done.